# Quicksort time complextiy analysis (Analysis of recurrence equation)

Tags: time-complexity

Quicksort's recurrence equation is

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) + theta(n)
```

if pivot always divides the original array into two same-sized sub arrays.

so the overall time complexity would be O(nlogn)

But what if the ratio of the two sub-lists is always 1:99?

The equation definitely would be `T(n) = T(n/100) + T(99n/100) + theta(n)`

But how can I derive time complexity from the above equation?

I've read other answer which describes that we can ignore T(n/100) since T(99n/100) will dominate the overall time complexity.

But I quite cannot fully understand.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Plug `T(n) = n log(n) + Θ(n)` and you get

```
n log(n) + Θ(n) = n/100 log(n/100) + 99n/100 log(99n/100) + Θ(n/100) + Θ(99n/100) + Θ(n)
                = n log(n)/100 + 99n log(n)/100 - n/100 log(100) - 99n/100 log(99/100) + Θ(n)
                = n log(n) + Θ(n)
```

In fact any fraction will work:

```
T(n) = T(pn) + T((1-p)n) + Θ(n)
```

is solved by `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: Simply plugging in a guess won't confirm its correctness (or completeness); e.g. `T(n) = Θ(n)` also works. Another method e.g. Akra-Bazzi or finding upper & lower bounds, is needed here